# Can you remove circular dependency of inner class factories?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

Let's say I have two classes but they can only be created via a factory, and in order to enforce that, I'm making the factories internal classes of the object they're creating so they can access private constructors.  In this case, one class has a need to create instances of the other class, and the second class has a need to create instances of the first one:

```
public class A
{
    public class Factory
    {
        private readonly B.Factory bFactory;

        public Factory(B.Factory bFactory)
        {
            this.bFactory = bFactory;
        }

        public A Build()
        {
            return new A(this.bFactory);
        }
    }
    private A(B.Factory bFactory)
    {
    }
}

public class B
{
    public class Factory
    {
        private readonly A.Factory aFactory;

        public Factory(A.Factory aFactory)
        {
            this.aFactory = aFactory;
        }

        public B Build()
        {
            return new B(this.aFactory);
        }
    }
    private B(A.Factory aFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

Normally I would resolve this by creating another factory called `ABFactory` that can create both `A` and `B` instances and I would make `A` and `B` both declare a dependency on `ABFactory`, but in that case `ABFactory` can't access the private constructors of both `A` and `B`.

Assuming the semantics are right (in this case it makes logical sense for an `A` to return an instance of `B` and for that `B` to return an instance of another `A`) then what's the best way to resolve this?

### **Update 1**

My solution so far is to create a new class called a `CircularDependencyResolver`.  Each of the two factories declares a dependency on that rather than the other factory.  Each one registers itself (`this`) with that resolver in their own constructor.  When they go to build their respective objects, they call the `Resolve` method on the resolver, which looks for the other registered factory, or throws an exception.

The problem of course is that we've put off resolving `A` or `B`'s dependency until when we actually need to create it, rather than at program start, but it does work.

I'm still interested in other solutions though.

Comment: Although some containers may support this, I think it's basically a design flaw.  I would always try to re-design to remove the circular dependency all together.  cycles cause problems on so many levels (GC, compilation, instantiation, etc.) that it's generally a technical debt that you don't want to take on

Comment: @PeterRitchie - even if I had no circular dependency (so I had an `ABFactory`) I still can't make that factory call both private constructors.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: The semantics cannot be right. In a philosophical way, if A can only be created when an instance of B is existing (I don't see the relevance of the factory pattern here, compared to conventional construction in this case, because you just move the problem code-wise, but not semantic wise) and B can only be created when A is existing, then there is no way, any of both can be created, as long as none of both exists.

There must be one, which can be created without the other, except A and B are part of the same thing, which is not the case here (as B should create an own instance of A). You need to make one a property of the other.

Maybe it helps to have a look at the difference of the concepts *aggregation* and *composition* in OOP to get the semantics straight,

By the way, it doesn't really matter whether you're looking at it in an dependency injection context or not, because you can't create instances any way.

Might be, I'm missing something, though... Interesting question!

**EDIT:**

Ok, what about this, then:

```cs
public class A
{
    private int _privateInt;

    private B CreateB()
    {
        return B.Factory.Build();
    }

    public static class Factory
    {
        public static A Build()
        {
            return new A {_privateInt = 1};
        }
    }

    private A()
    {
    }
}

public class B
{
    public static class Factory
    {
        public static B Build()
        {
            return new B();
        }
    }

    private B()
    {
    }
}
```

But maybe, I don't really get the problem?

**EDIT 2:**

I can't really picture your scenario, but why do you need to pass the factory of the one class to the other, especially in the context of DI? If you want to get fresh instances of one class (say B) from the other (A), why don't you let the container create that instance for you?

**EDIT 3:**

If your container supports resolving `Lazy` initializers for your instances, you can use those as the types of your constructor parameters:

```
public A(Lazy>B> b) {}
```

Comment: Think of it this way: a `ViewPurchaseOrder` controller, which can create a `ViewCustomer` controller, which can create a `ViewAllPurchaseOrdersForCustomer` controller, which can create a `ViewPurchaseOrder` controller, etc.  In this case the last `ViewPurchaseOrder` controller is a different instance than the first.

Comment: Just to clarify, both `A` and `B` can potentially be created from other places, but they both have the ability to create the other.  They only require that the other's *factory* be created first.  This code was originally refactored from a non-factory approach where `A` just directly instantiated `B` (using `new`) and vice-versa.

Comment: Reply to your "edit 2": I don't pass the container into my objects.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: You don't necessarily need to, depending on the container. For example in Autofac or MEF you could solve it with passing Lazy<A> in the constructor of B, which is like a 'container made' factory....

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would of course agree with what @PeterRitchie said in his comment as Cyclic Dependencies are a powerful design smell, secondly to break cyclic dependencies i go with an advise i read in Marc Seemann's book [Dependency Inject in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) and that is:

> Attempt to address cycles by using events. If that fails, try an
>   Observer. Only if you’re still unsuccessful should you consider
>   breaking the cycle by using PROPERTY INJECTION.

If all of this fails, i would use the solution that Object Oriented Languages are famous for which is to introduce another dependency or abstraction to break the cycle which is what you actually did.